# Use SQLKata to update a table based on a join of multiple tables

Tags: sqlkata

I don't think this can be written as a CTE, and I don't see it documented at https://sqlkata.com/docs/update.

How would I write this as a SQLKata query?

```
UPDATE 
    tableA
SET 
    column2 = 'foo'
FROM tableA
     JOIN tableB
     ON tableA.column1 = tableB.column1
WHERE 
    tableB.column3 = 'bar';
```